# Imports System.Data.SqlClient .... Imports System.Data ....?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, import, system.data

i am using both VISUAL WEB DEVELOPER 2010 & VISUAL STUDIO 2012 EXPRESS EDITION.
While writing WINDOWS FORMS APPLICATION ... i used only one statement to work with DataSet,DataTable and Datarow.It is,

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

But while developing WEB APPLICATIONS in ASP.NET using VISUAL WEB DEVELOPER 2010 , i had to use 2 statements.They are,

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
```

If i did not import **System.Data** , *DataSet, DataRow, DataTable* are not being recognized.
What is the reason..??
I heard that BASE CLASS LIBRARY ( BCL ) is same for both windows & web application..??

Comment: Have a look at the references tab in your project. I assume that `System.Data` is imported by default in VB.NET-winforms applications. You can add other dll's as well there if you don't want to include the imports statement in all your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a reference to the System.Data assembly, that holds the System.Data namespace, including System.Data.SqlClient. Once you added the reference, use

```
Import System.Data.SqlClient
```

for a VB.NET project or

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

for a C# project.

The Import / Using statement makes the SqlClient namespace (located in the System.Data assembly) available to your code.

Answer (score 0):

goto properties of your project change .net client profile to .net profile now check it

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Studio 2010

Step1 - Goto Project Property under Project Menu.
Step2 - Under References of the Project Click Add
Step3 - Select .Net Tab and select System.Data and OK

:)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties and Services check "Enable client application services".